# Is it possible to modify a console game graphics (Xbox 360)?

Tags: rendering, 3d, direct3d

There's a thing called [ENB](http://enbdev.com/) for PC which works by modifying render functions calls of the games and applying additional effects. I wonder if there is a similar way for console games.

Comment: It's probably feasible, but will have to be done on a game-to-game basis. More recent consoles, like the PS3/XB360 also use shaders, so assuming you can reverse engineer the assets, you could modify the shaders to apply additional effects. But having the protected disc complicates things, so you would probably also need a jailbroken device to run the modified software as if it was homebrew.